# Libreria JSZip no funciona fuera de su pagina oficial

Tags: javascript, jszip

necesito usar la libreria JSZip o su variante JSZip-utils para comprimir archivos (en mi caso externos mediante URL), pero lo extraño es que por mas que importe la libreria, use el codigo de ejemplo en mi proyecto como tambien en paginas tipo jsfiddle, no funciona puesto que nunca arroja el mensaje para descarga.
Cabe decir que el codigo original de la pagina trae 2 lineas donde se setea la compresion de imagen o archivos las cuales en mi ejemplo las quite y solo deje la linea que crea un TXT que es lo mas simple de ahi, solo para ver si funcionaba con lo mas sencillo pero aun asi no funciona.

https://stuk.github.io/jszip/

```
 var zip = new JSZip();
 zip.file("Hello.txt", "Hello World\n"); //Crea archivo Hello con frase Hello world.
 var img = zip.folder("images"); //seteo de carpeta de imagenes
 img.file("smile.gif", imgData, {base64: true}); //compresion de archivos de imagen.
 zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
 .then(function(content) {
 // see FileSaver.js
 saveAs(content, "example.zip");
 });
```

En el proyecto puse unos alert para ver por donde pasaba la funcion y a pesar de que pasa por la compresion final, no se abre el popup de descarga

https://jsfiddle.net/6yv7p2nf/4/

Alguien podria ayudarme de por que no se genera el mensaje para la descarga?

Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se debe que la función `saveAs` no esta definida.

## Solución:

La misma puedes encontrarla aquí [`https://stuk.github.io/jszip/vendor/FileSaver.js`](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/vendor/FileSaver.js)

**Repositorio original**: [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js)

## Demo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>

<script src="https://kripken.github.io/sql.js/js/sql.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.5/jszip.js"></script>
<script src="https://stuk.github.io/jszip/vendor/FileSaver.js"></script>

<body>

<button onclick="zip()">Descargar</button>

<script>

function zip(){
var zip = new JSZip();

// Agregamos contenido en un archivo de texto de alto nivel.
zip.file("Hola.txt", "Hola Mundo\n");
alert("Creo Archivo de texto");

// Generar el archivo .zip de forma asíncrona.
zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"}).then(function(contenido) {
alert("Entra a guardado de archivo");
    saveAs(contenido, "archivo.zip");
});}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excelente!, habia visto varias veces el archivo filesaver.js pero nunca pense que era dependiente, pensaba que correspondia a una opcion extra. Muchas gracias Marcos, estuve un dia completo probando y no entendia por que. Saludos!